# Nothing happens when scaling faces along x-axes

Tags: edit-mode, transforms

I'm trying to scale my faces along the x-axes, so the faces become smaller like shown in the first picture. However, when I do it, nothing happens as can be seen in the second picture.

Scaling along the Z and Y-axes is fine.
Applying Scale doesn't make a difference.

How can I scale the faces along the x-axes so they become smaller and I get that more tapered shape?

[image]

[image]

**EDIT**
I have my pivot point set on individual origins.
The first image is basically what it should be, so that is what it will look like if I am able to scale along the x-axes in the second picture. It does feel like I have created extra faces, but when I dissolve them and try to scale it doesn't make any difference.

[image]

**The file:**
[image]

Comment: What is your [Transform Pivot Point](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/pivot_point/index.html)?

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie I was about to ask that! Please show an image of the whole screen including the top toolbar.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are showing in the second screenshot - there the faces are definitely smaller in X direction as in the image above. Although, in the first it looks like the faces have the width of the gap so it is one segment in the center, in the second there is another row of faces to the left and right. Could it be each gap is made out of three segments and you only scale the inner ones? Of course this doesn't change the taper since the outer faces stay in place.

Comment: It's possible you've accidentally created extra rings of faces, there, with a bevel or an extrusion, and you're scaling those, leaving the edges connected to the wider segments behind.

Comment: I think you should share your blend file or at least this part of the model. https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Looking at your file, @RobinBetts explanation seems to be the good one. And it seems you have that several times. Use merge by distance to solve it.

Comment: @lemon that's indeed what it look like, but dissolve faces should then be the solution right? And that doesn't make a difference

Comment: No, dissolve faces doesn't do that.  You can merge by distance or you can do a degenerate dissolve.

Comment: @DPlayground I downloaded your file, selected all and hit M > _Merge_ > _By Distance_. This removed 304 vertices, you have basically every edge in the smaller rings doubled, and not only the ones you try to scale down, the ones on both ends as well. Selecting all objects and merging by distance removes 368 vertices all in all.